# Advice for web API to peform calculations

Tags: java, selenium, web-applications

I am developing a java application (Java 8), that is supposed to make use of the following website (https://calculator.carbonfootprint.com/calculator.aspx) to calculate your Co2 emission given the user input in the java application. For this I would need a web API to communicate between java and the website.

I have come across various API's, for example Selenium (this WebDriver API is mostly used for web-app testing though, so that does not really fit my project, I think.)

So, I am looking for some advice which java library to use when it comes filling in forms on the given webpage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean you want to automate the (user) interaction with the HTML form then submit it then parse the resulting HTML to find out the emission? Is carbonfootprint.com OK with that use of their service? I guess it would be far easier to find out the REST API that probably lays behind and make use of it (with their owner's permission...).

Comment: Alright, thanks for the quick response. Could you maybe list some REST API's that you would recommend me to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Hugo,

If you're a Spring user then you definately have to look into the RestTemplate : 
https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template

Otherwise, Jersey's client works too : 
https://www.baeldung.com/jersey-jax-rs-client

HTH!

Comment: Yes! Thanks! The RestTemplate is just what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is actually a framework which controls web browsers. It is mostly used for automated testing but it could be used in your project. I hope it is clear that this will open a browser (Chrome, Firefox,...) which interacts with the mentioned page. (Maybe you could use selenium with headless chrome?)

As @Highbrainer already mentioned, it would be the best way to use the underlying (REST?) API. For that you probably need to ask the owner to give you information about that API and if you can use it.